# JSON.parse(json_string_from_php) produces weird array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm having a bit of difficulty with transferring a JSON object from the server to the client-side javascript

I have a rows of data fetched from MySQL query stored into `$result`

Here's the code:

```
var json = '<?= json_encode($result->fetch_all()) ?>';
var word_list = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(word_list);     //index.php:23
console.log(json);          //index.php:24
```

This is the result in chrome console:
[image: number of arrays in the concise version and expanded version don't match]

Can someone tell me: 
1. Why line 23 shows length of 5 when folded, then only show length of 4 when unfolded?
2. Where did word5 go? FYI, the word that disappears changes every time I refresh.

Comment: maybe you have to scroll down??

Comment: @Grumpy Nope. That's it. that's the expanded version

Comment: I **am** able to reproduce this, but I doubt your code above is what is causing this, unless you have more code we are not seeing. I'm going to post a way to reproduce this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I purposely hovered over the little "i" to reveal its tooltip. It states "Object state below is captured upon **first expansion**.

This means that if you print the array, don't expand it, modify the array (say with a `pop()`) then when you expand it you will see the *modified* array.

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wuvadu/2/embed?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` logs your state of the object to the console when it is hitting the console.log while inspecting the array (or any object) shows you the current state of it.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5].map(function(){ return new String(); });
console.log(a);
a.pop();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input!! That definitely helped a lot. It got me out of the hole I was in. Now I know where to look for the little bug.